# Apache2 and SSL, some users can't connect through proxy

Tags: ssl, proxy, apache-2.2

I have an apache2 server that hosts a site using ssl (only site on the box). Some users at one company have trouble loading the site, they are behind a proxy and get this error

- Error Code: 502 Proxy Error. The host server is unreachable.
  (10065)
- IP Address: 50.56.98.28
- Date: 18/04/2011 13:08:01
- Server: remlxsobpx02h.ssibouter.rbsssi.net
- Source: proxy

Does anyone know if this problem is on my side? We have an old copy of the site on a hosted server (also ssl) and they can connect to it.

*updated to clear up my grammar

Comment: Some users behind that proxy or some users, all of whom are behind that proxy?

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on the type and version of the proxy they are running but I would have the administrator of that proxy go through the logs and see if they are seeing errors that have something to do with the intermediate certificate on your site.

I would also verify that ssl is configured properly using curl or OpenSSL to make sure that there isn't a configuration problem you aren't seeing because you are using a browser like IE or FireFox to connect with your site.  IE is not a good browser to use for testing that ssl is using a valid configuration--most browsers are no longer good for this purpose.

I've also seen in the past that geographic distance can be a factor is the ttl on an ssl client connection is too low.  For example, users in China used to have problems connecting to my sites that were hosted in the Northeast United States.

Comment: Hi mahnsc, thanks for your comments. I still haven't heard back from the IT in charge of that proxy. I have tested the SSL with a few tools and they all report a good SSL. It could be the distance, the server is in the US and this group of users is in the UK (but my pingdom.com monitor is showing 300-400ms response times). Well, whatever happens, I thank you for your advise.